# Are trees required in New Leaf to have a perfect town?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

In the older games, I could have no trees, but lots of flowers and have the perfect town status. Does it work the same way in New Leaf?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Animal Crossing wiki article on perfect towns](http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Perfect_Town), you do need trees.

> In Animal Crossing: New Leaf, you need 110-200 trees and over 75 flowers in your town.

Comment: Well, the same wiki also says "In games with the acre system you need 12-16 trees and 6-10 flowers planted in each acre." And I had no trees but many flowers in games with the acre system, and I still got a perfect town status.

Comment: @Julum-Ei New Leaf doesn't use the acres system. The wiki states this clearly.